# Php warning message on date_timestamp

Tags: wordpress, datetime, php-7.1

Hello I am trying to get the timestamp from a DateTime object in a wordpress plugin. Despite I manage to get the timestamp I receive also a warning (php version 7.1.26). This is what I have done so far:

```
$x=$season->getStartDate();
//DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-07-12 14:45:14.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )

$timestamp=date_timestamp_get($x); 
//1562942714
//Warning: date_timestamp_get() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given
```

How can I eliminate the warning (without disabling warning messages)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already an object that you can use. So try `$season->getTimestamp();`.

https://secure.php.net/manual/de/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: Now I am receiving this: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on null"  but thanks for your help..

Comment: Sorry... yes then `$x` is not the object. Then use use `$season` variable.